# Exceptions with Microsoft Teams Connector - errors 500 "Install app id lookup failure", "Cannot read property 'ConfigurationsVisible'"

Tags: configuration, save, settings, connector, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a connector for Teams, and constantly getting 500 errors in web client during lengthy debugging sessions. 
What I usually do are multiple subsequent `microsoftTeams.settings.get/setSettings` calls, adding/removing sideload package, adding/removing connector from my team, sending messages to Outlook web hooks and so on. Everything is working fine, but after some period of time I start getting errors for currently used connector id as described below. This definitely has something to do with Connectors backend stuff because creating a new team and new connector in Connectors Developer Dashboard usually helps me to proceed.
Example. When I'm sideloading new version of extension, choosing team, then the channel, clicking "Set up", this error pops up in the console and I'm being redirected to Connectors list for a channel.

```
2018-12-24T15:05:42.342Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1545227948597,"timestamp":1545663941386,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"Manage","name":"ClientError","nonPIIInfo":"{\"name\":\"Install app id lookup failure f0e3cf15-cef0-48f1-bf75-25785bf62c63\"}"}
```

My connector is present in the bottom of the list and I can access its config page, but cannot save the configuration - getting empty 500 error (`"{\"exception\":{}}"`). Expected behavior - sideload, choose team, choose channel, "Set up", redirect to a connector configuration page, save configuration.
When I'm clicking on my sideloaded connector in this list I'm getting another error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConfigurationsVisible' of undefined\",\"stack\":\"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConfigurationsVisible' of undefined\\n    at p.ConfigurationsCtrl.n.toggleConfigurationDetails (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/app.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:1:57930)\\n    at fn (eval at compile (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:124257), <anonymous>:4:698)\\n    at t (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:67388)\\n    at u (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:143542)\\n    at p.$eval (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:77312)\\n    at p.$apply (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:77546)\\n    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:143594)\\n    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:28337)\\n    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:25042)\"}"}
```

Is there any way to troubleshoot/"reset" connector other than deleting and recreating it from scratch? My latest connector id that has this issue is `1b263a28-4d0f-45bd-8f76-da573f11bd6e`.
p.s. I also suspect connector settings are cached somewhere, because today I've changed connector configuration url in code, manifests and Connectors Dashboard, but it was still hitting to the "old" route. Switching to another connector id from list helped.
**UPDATE**
The "faulty" connector also causes another 500 error when trying to remove it from the channel (right after 'Remove' click in configuration tab):

```
2018-12-25T16:45:56.300Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1545227949598,"timestamp":1545756356278,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"Manage","name":"ClientError","nonPIIInfo":"{\"name\":\"Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress\\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest\",\"stack\":\"Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress\\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest\\n    at https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:3340\\n    at nt (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:73371)\\n    at p.$digest (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:75654)\\n    at p.$apply (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/vendor.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:6:77596)\\n    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Static/app.min.js?v=16.01.1362.003:1:59080)\\n    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:28337)\\n    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:25042)\\n    at Object.trigger (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:27423)\\n    at Object.simulate (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:30815)\\n    at HTMLDocument.r (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4:1788)\"}"}
```

After that I click 'Remove' in the popup, web client freezes and returns to connector list without refresh. My connector is still listed there as if it was not removed (it actually did).

Comment: Are you getting the same issue with multiple teams? Did you try setting up your Connector in new team all together instead of creating new connector? Could you please share latest connector Id and configUrl so that we can try it?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes, I do experience this issue with multiple teams. Moreover, I activated another O365 subscription on completely new Microsoft account and tried my connector there with the same result. And to add even more, after this issue occurs I can't even add your sample C# connector created by @Bill Bliss, it fails to save configuration for the first time after load as well. My latest connector id is `1b263a28-4d0f-45bd-8f76-da573f11bd6e`, configUrl `https://dec54014.ngrok.io/Connector/Setup.html`. validDomains are set to this specific domain without any wildcards.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I'm not sure, but connectors data caching on the Outlook side may be causing this issue. Today I've updated configuration page url for connector in Connectors Developer Dashboard, and now constantly getting error 500 with empty error details during connector save.

Comment: Your ngrok URLs are getting expired before I test it. Could you please sign up in ngrok website to get one free url which doesn't expire?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Here it is. Connector 1b263a28-4d0f-45bd-8f76-da573f11bd6e, configuration page https://105305e5.ngrok.io/Connector/Setup.html.

Comment: Your application is not running, if you could run now I'll take a look right away.